# How to upload file using below HTML script in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I tried to send_keys() directly to attached path file but getting error can any on guide me how to upload file.

below is my selenium python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait



browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,20)
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')

browser.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/img').click()

att = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ow6 > div.M8H8pb > c-wiz > div.ea0Lbe > div > div.gIYJUc > div.f6GA0 > div > div.ZeVBtc > span')))
att.send_keys('C:/Users/avu/caha.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong web element.
To upload file with Selenium you need to use the following locator:

```py
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys(file_path)
```

This element is not visible or clickable, so `presence_of_element_located` should be used in case you want to use `WebDriverWait`.
**UPD**
Your code should be as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait



browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,20)
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')

browser.find_element(XPATH, "//img[@alt='Camera search']").click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys('C:/Users/avu/caha.png')
```

Possibly you even don't need to use `browser.find_element(XPATH, "//img[@alt='Camera search']").click()` line.

Comment: then also file not got attached. I m using path like this file_path = "C:\\Users\\automation_new\\cvu\\12.zip" is this ok

Comment: Try using single, not double. Also, sometimes there are several elements matching `"//input[@type='file']"` locator. In this case you will need to target the proper element precisely

Comment: When i use single \ code editor throws error

Comment: Well, your question is missing debugging details..

Comment: can u tell me how to attach zip file using above HTML script

Comment: I already answered you. My answer should work in almost 100% cases. Seems your problem is with some other part of your code. To help more we have to se ALL your code including a link to the page you working on

Comment: below is my full correct code but then also file is not get attached. --->


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,20)
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')

browser.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/img').click()

att = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ow6 > div.M8H8pb > c-wiz > div.ea0Lbe > div > div.gIYJUc > div.f6GA0 > div > div.ZeVBtc > span')))
att.click()
att.send_keys('C:/Users/avu/caha.png')

Comment: It's absolutely not readable. Please post your code inside the question.

Comment: check now I have change full question.

Comment: You didn't do what I wrote you.. See the updated answer